# É possível chamar function sem ser por onclick?

Tags: javascript, funções

É um ciclo, onde a cada rodada a função tem que ser executada, andei pesquisando e só achei como chamar por onclick. Acredito que seja feito por um script, mas não acho o código.

http://exage-rado.tumblr.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var imgm = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
    var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
    function control(mostra) {
        if(mostra == "all"){
            for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
                imgm[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
            for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
                txt[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }else if(mostra == "image"){
            for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
                imgm[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
            for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
                txt[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }else{
            for (var i=0;i<imgm.length;i+=1){
                imgm[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            for (var i=0;i<txt.length;i+=1){
                txt[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

.
.
.

```
<div id="button">
    <input id="tudo" type="button" value="All" onclick=control('all') />
    <input id="imagem" type="button" value="Image" onclick=control('image') />
    <input id="texto" type="button" value="Text" onclick=control('text') />
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
{block:Posts}
<a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank" title="Click to reblog">
<div id="posts">
    <div class="text">
        {block:Text}{block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}
        {block:Quote}
            <div id="postquote">“{Quote}”</div><br>
            {block:Source}<div id="sourcequote"> — {Source}</div>{/block:Source}
        {/block:Quote}
        {block:Link}
            <a href="{URL}"><h1>{Name}</h1></a>
            {block:Description}<p>{Description}</p>{/block:Description}
        {/block:Link}
        {block:Chat}<ul class="chat">{block:Lines}<li class="user_{UserNumber}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}&nbsp;{Line}</li>{/block:Lines}</ul>{/block:Chat}
        {block:Answer}
            <table width="500px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="415px" class="question">{Question}</td>
                    <td width="30px"><span class="questionarrow">◤</span></td>
                    <td width="64px" class="asking"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-64}><br>{Asker}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="answer">{Answer}</div>
        {/block:answer}
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        {block:Photo}<center><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/></center>
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photo}
        {block:Photoset}<center>{Photoset-500}</center>
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Photoset}
        {block:Video}{Video-500}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Video}
    </div>

    {block:Audio}<span class="audio"><center>{AudioPlayerBlack}</center></span>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:Audio}
    <div id="ssource">
        {block:ContentSource}
            <a href="{SourceURL}">{lang:Source}:{block:SourceLogo}
            <img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
            {/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo}</a>
        {/block:ContentSource}
    </div>
</div>
</a>{block:HasTags}<br>{block:Tags} <a href="{TagURL}"><b>#</b>{Tag}</a>&nbsp;{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: é no tumblr, então tem um bloco, block:post, e a cada post ele carrega todas as divs dentro dele, então quando carregar quero que execute a função, que é um filtro do que deve aparecer ou não

Comment: Além disso, acredito que o problema seja, na verdade, como obter uma ***referência*** às `<div>`s criadas pela API que ele está usando.

Comment: coloquei todo o código que acredito ter a ver, como veem, a cada postagem, tudo entre {block:post} e {/block:post} se repete, estou tentando fazer um filtro, como podem conferir lá no link, mas só funciona com as postagens já carregadas... Pensei que a solução seria chamar a função a cada post...

Comment: acabo de descobrir que não sei como funciona, ele só faz um loop com as 8 primeiras postagens, as demais não entendo como...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que neste caso pode usar o evento `DOMNodeInserted`.

```
var div = document.getElementById('involves');
div.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
  console.log(e.target); // veja na consola os novos elementos

  // corra a sua função
  control('all');
});
```

Este oscultador de evento vai ser ativado a cada vez que fôr inserido elementos DOM dentro de `#involves`. Aí pode correr a sua função e pode também ver que elementos foram adicionados.

**Nota:** O seu código (e confirma-se no link que colocou agora) está a repetir todas as IDs a cada post. IDs têm de ser únicas.

**Nota2:** O evento `DOMNodeInserted` irá provavelmente ser substituido no futuro por [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) mas que por enquanto só estão acessíveis para o IE11+ e browsers modernos

O código nesse caso seria:

```
var div = document.getElementById('involves');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // corra a sua função
    control('all');  
});

// configuração:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(div , config);

// Caso queira parar o observador
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: não entendi... até tentei, mas não deu...

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira pegue o código que está no inicio da resposta e coloque no fundo da sua página, dentro de tags script e antes do body. Coloque um alert (ou use o console.log que coloquei) e vai ver ele a ser chamado quando a página carregar novos posts.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, achei uma solução simples e 100% funcional                          window.onscroll = function () {
control();    
}

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira Fazendo no onscroll você vai ativar a função várias vezes a mais, denecessariamente.

Comment: sim, eu sei, mas não achei outra maneira

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira da maneira que eu sugeri na resposta a função corre 1 vez por cada post adicionado. Parece-me mais razoável que o scrol...

Comment: mas não funcionou

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira funciona bem para mim quando testo na consola do seu site. Pode mostrar como implementou no seu site?

Comment: como só preciso que chame control, deixei assim:

   var div = document.getElementById('involves');
   div.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(){control();});

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yx8HYmsM

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira tenho de sair mas vou rever esse código e fazer melhorias e colocar aqui de novo mais tarde.

Comment: muito obrigado, até

Comment: @RodrigodeOliveira testa assim (só juntei o meu código no dinal): http://pastebin.com/q5DjLnuh

Comment: deu, agora não entendi mais nada, aquela hora eu dei só um ctrl+c e ctrl+v e não deu... mas valeu cara, valeu mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez declarada, uma função pode ser chamada em qualquer trecho de JavaScript.

Para as finalidades comuns dos scripts de Internet, pode-se dizer que quase sempre as chamadas de funções e outras operações são feitas em resposta a eventos: o carregamento da página, o click de um botão, uma alteração em um `<input />`, entre outros.

Porém, nada impede o programador de chamar a função como primeira instrução da primeira linha de *scripting*; o problema, no entanto, é que, por vezes, nem todos os elementos HTML e demais scripts foram carregados na memória, o que costuma causar erros.

De qualquer forma, seu problema é mais relacionado a ***saber qual elemento escutar por eventos*** do que propriamente a *"chamar function sem ser por onclick"*. Assim, sugiro que você verifique a documentação do plugin/API que você está usando, pois deve haver suporte à adição de uma função *callback* como ouvinte do evento de criação de cada uma dessas `<div>`s às quais você se refere.

Comment: Porque deram -1? ..

Comment: Seria legal mesmo, saber! :D assim dá pra melhorar, se for o caso.